# If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and every point of $[a,b]$ is a local maximum point, then $f$ is a constant function.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Claim to prove:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and every point of $[a,b]$ is a local maximum point, then $f$ is a constant function.

I think I have a valid argument, which I will include below, but it strikes me as a little clunky. If there are alternative basic methods (I think there are topology arguments, which are foreign to me, so preferably not those), please share.

---

We will prove that for any $c_1, c_2 \in [a,b]: f(c_1)=f(c_2)$, which is equivalent to saying that there is a constant $k$ such that for any $x\in[a,b]: f(x)=k$...i.e. $f$ is a constant function on $[a,b]$.

To do this, we will show that the following two statements are true:

$\left [\forall x \in [c_1,c_2): \exists \delta_x \gt 0 : \forall y \in [x,x+\delta_x):f(x) \geq f(y) \right ] \rightarrow \left [\forall x \in [c_1,c_2]: f(x) \leq f(c_1) \right] \quad(*)$

$\left [\forall x \in (c_1,c_2]: \exists \delta_x \gt 0 : \forall y \in (x-\delta_x,x]:f(y) \leq f(x) \right ] \rightarrow \left [ \forall x \in [c_1,c_2]: f(x) \leq f(c_2)\right] \quad(**)$

Together, these two statements ensure that $f(c_1)=f(c_2)$, which will then prove our overarching claim specific to the interval $[a,b]$.

---

To prove $(*)$, consider the set
$S= \left\{x\in[c_1,c_2]: \forall y \in [c_1,x] \big(f(y) \leq f(c_1)\big)\right\}$.

$c_1 \in S$ and therefore $S$ is non-empty. Further, $S$ has an upper bound of $c_2$. Therefore $S$ has a least upper bound $\alpha$. Note that because $[c_1,c_2] \subseteq [a,b]$, $\alpha \in [a,b]$.

Suppose $\alpha=c_1$. Firstly, we must have $\alpha \in S$, but this is not possible because, by assumption, there is a right neighborhood of $\alpha$ that includes elements all $\leq f(c_1)$, which would disqualify $\alpha$ as an upper bound. So $\alpha \neq c_1$.

Next, suppose $\alpha = x \in (c_1,c_2)$. If $\alpha \in S$, we will encounter a similar issue as above. So $\alpha \notin S$, which means that $f(\alpha) \gt f(c_1)$. By continuity of $f$ on the interval $[c_1,c_2]$, we can apply the *Intermediate Value Theorem* (IVT) on the interval $[c_1,\alpha]$. In particular, there must be an $x \in (c_1,\alpha)$ such that $f(x)=\frac{f(\alpha)+f(c_1)}{2} \gt f(c_1)$, but this would mean that $x \notin S$. Moreover, for any $x' \gt x$, we must then have $x' \notin S$. As such, $\alpha$ would be disqualified as being the *least* upper bound. Therefore, $\alpha = c_2$.

Suppose $\alpha=c_2 \notin S$. A similar argument using the IVT on the interval $[c_1,\alpha]$ would, once again, lead to a contradiction. So $\alpha \in S$, which means $c_2 \in S$. Therefore, for all $x \in [c_1,c_2]: f(x) \leq f(c_1)$, proving $(*)$.

A similar structured argument (using the greatest lower bound $\beta$) working from right to left will prove $(**)$. Use the set $S= \left\{x\in[c_1,c_2]: \forall y \in [y,c_2] \big(f(y) \leq f(c_2)\big)\right\}$.

Together, we then have that $f(c_1)=f(c_2)$. These two points were arbitrary elements of $[a,b]$, so we can generalize and reach our desired conclusion.

Comment: What do you mean with “maximum point”? If I consider $ x \in [a, b]$ to be a maximum iff $f(x) \geq f(y)$ for all $y \in [a, b]$, then, if $x, y \in [a, b]$, since every point is a maximum, $f(x) \geq f(y) \geq f(x)$, which means $f(x) = f(y)$. This means that $f$ is constant (notice how I didn’t use continuity…). Maybe you mean **local** maximum

Comment: @Gauss: I assume the OP means local maximum. And in this case, continuity is required.

Comment: @TonyK While writing the comment, I realized that could be the case and promptly edited it. Still, I think it should be explicitly written in the question

Comment: @Gauss: I agree.

Comment: @Gauss sorry about that: good catch.

Comment: @TonyK thank you - the change has been made

Answer (score 2):

The function $f$ is continuous on the compact $[a,b]$, so it achieves its global minimum at a point $m\in[a,b]$. Now $C:=\{x\in[a,b]: f(x)=f(m)\}$ is non-empty ($m\in C$), closed in $[a,b]$ (it is equal to $f^{-1}\langle\{f(m)\}\rangle$ and $f$ is continuous), and open in $[a,b]$ (because any $x\in C$ is a local maximum point, so $f(m)=f(x)\ge f(t)\ge f(m)$ for all $t$ sufficiently close to $x$). Since $[a,b]$ is a connected set, this proves that $C=[a,b]$.

Answer (score -1):

> If f is continuous on [a,b] and every point of [a,b] is a local maximum point, then f is a constant function.

an heuristic approach could be this one:

- basic idea: choose a random point, $p$, then check if $p-1$, and $p+1$ are the same point, then repeat that with every points.

this could result in an infinite sequence in which you add a small value over and over again, until you reach the bounds of the function.

$\sum_{i=0}^n f(x_i) = f(x_p)$,  where x_p are the next points and the past points to be checked.
the sum could be updated like a for-loop in coding, instead of a constant n, you could put a condition to be satisfied: if it's true, then go inside the summation body; otherwise go outside.